# My 6 month old cat suckles and kneads on a blanket

Tags: cats, feeding

My cat suckles and kneads on this really soft blanket that I have and I think might resemble his mother. I was wondering if I could bottle feed him, but I dont know what or how I should do that? I know adult cats cannot have milk or cream. Should I bottle feed him or just let him continue to just suckle on the blanket? Thank you!

Comment: Even though your cat is not a fully qualified adult; this behaviour seen in many adult cats too. check this question for more information http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10355/my-adult-cat-kneads-and-sucks-on-my-blanket-like-a-kitten-why

Answer (score 9):

My 8 year old cat still does that as well. It's usually when a kitten was taken away from their mother too soon. My cat was abandoned when he was 3 weeks old. I did bottle feed him for 2 or 3 more weeks, then weaned him to solid food.

Your kitten doesn't need a bottle -- he'll just chew the nipple off. Just comfort and pet him/her, speak soothingly and all will be well. The suckling is a self-comforting device your kitten uses to feel safe. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's normal and your cat doesn't need bottle feeding.

I had such situation for a few times. 
My parents' cat was taken from her mother when she was 4 weeks. After she got into our house, she sucked my toys (I was 11 years old), our blankets and my sister's long hair so in the morning she looked like a broom :). She only stopped after 3 or 4 years.

My own cat was taken early from her mother as well. Firstly she liked to suck blankets, now she licks socks sometimes, but doesn't do it often now.

Just make your kitten feel safe and everything will be OK. Maybe it needs some private place like a kitten house or basket with soft blanket.

Answer (score 2):

My 5 month year old cat does that as well, she was taken away from her mom at around 8 weeks, I am not sure if that's too early or not. I recently got a faux fur throw blanket and she loves to suckle on it. There's a thing called the catsifier and its a soft cat shaped thing with nipples that cats can suckle on if you don't want them suckling on anything else. Here is a link to their website: https://www.catsifier.com/

Answer (score 1):

My kitten does it when she is preparing to go to sleep or when she would like to be stroked. It's more like she needs a warming cuddles... we asked our vet, is it because she was taken too early from her mother, as we got our kitten without any information how old she was? He said that some cats just act like that where soft duvets are, so they feel like it's a mother's fur and is comforting them... But that is normal... I was told not to be worried, as his 10 years old cat does the same.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 month old kittens suck on my bed blanket every night.  They were with their mother for at least 10 weeks, so they weren't weaned too early. They came from my daughter's cat and we purposely made sure they were done nursing before I took them in.. I think they just like doing it because it's comforting and relaxing.